# pdf locking program for document generated in Word 2007

Tags: pdf

I am creating a Word Document and then saving it as a pdf for dissemination. Is there any free program that I could use to lock it?

Ideally I want to disable copying & modification. The lock does not have to be air tight against smart adversaries.

It only has to defeat the casual copier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pdf toolkit](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) has both free and nearly free tools that can do what you need - from the free, server, version just set an owner password and allow ScreenReaders plus possibly printing.

Comment: Thanks! I am looking into this program now.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/features) for every kind of creating PDFs on a Windows machine!

Some highlights:

- merge and rearrange
- restrict access/usage
- digitally signing with signatures
- can create also much other formats like PS, TIFF, PNG, JPEG, SVG, PSD, BMP, PCX, RAW,...
- profiles to save different settings
- automatic saving or define other "automatic actions" (mail, upload, scripts,...)
- COM-interface for scripting
- open source

The only downside is, you have to **uncheck some adware during installation**!